# How to check if a string starts with a capital letter in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code, I am trying to get the strings which starts with capital, but I don't know how! without linq I can do it but inside LINQ... no idea!

```cs
string[] queryValues1 = new string[10] {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven","nine", "ten" };
string[] queryValues2 = new string[3] { "A", "b", "c" };

var queryResult =
    from qResult in queryValues1
    from qRes in queryValues2
    where qResult.Length > 3
    where qResult.Length < 5
    where qRes[0].StartWithCapital //how to check if qRes started with a capital letter?
    select qResult + "\t" + qRes + Environment.NewLine;

foreach (var qResult in queryResult)
{
    textBox1.Text += qResult;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The earlier solutions here all assume `queryValues2` consists of strings with at least one character in them. While that is true of the example code, it isn't necessarily always true.

Suppose, instead, you have this:

```
string[] queryValues2 = new string[5] { "A", "b", "c", "", null };
```

(which might be the case if the string array is passed in by a caller, for example).

A solution that goes straight for `qRes[0]` will raise an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the `""` and a `NullReferenceException` on the `null`.

Therefore, a safer alternative for the general case would be to use this:

```
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qRes) && char.IsUpper(qRes[0])
```

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, all the earlier solutions were aimed at the example code presented, and error checking is left up to the OP (otherwise all our answers would have to have a *"you must do x y and z for error checking"* disclaimer). Your answer is correct, but is explicitly stating what everyone else is implicitly relying on the OP to take care of.

Comment: @slugster That assumes null or an empty string is invalid input. If it's valid input, and the answer doesn't address it, the answer is incomplete. Otherwise we might as well answer with `where qRes == "A"`, which will be true for all strings in the example that start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
where char.IsUpper(qRes[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Check `Char.IsUpper(qRes[0])`.

Comment: That's one `[0]` too many, I think: `qRes` is a `string`, so `qRes[0]` is already the `char` you need. Note that it will cause an exception to be thrown if it is called on an empty string, whereas I would consider the test "starts with an uppercase letter" to be a valid test that should return false.

Comment: hmm I got `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'char'`  when I tried to do `            var queryResult =
                from qResult in queryValues1
                from qRes in queryValues2
                where qResult.Length > 3
                where qResult.Length < 5
                where Char.IsUpper(qRes[0][0])
                select new { qResult, qRes };`

Comment: @hvd: You're right; I thought that his `qRes[0]`was a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
where Char.IsUpper(qRes.FirstOrdefault())
```

It is the same as outside LINQ.

Comment: `qRes[0]` is a single character (not an IEnumerable), so this line of code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: strange I actually changed it because I saw another answer use qRes[0][0] for the character. Changing it back

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (in this code arr is a string[]):

```
from a in arr
                    where ((int)a.ToCharArray()[0] >= 65 && (int)a.ToCharArray()[0] <= 90)
                    select a
```

The gist is to check whether the first character's ASCII value lies in the range of capital letters or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("\nLINQ : Find the uppercase words in a string : ");
        Console.Write("\n----------------------------------------------\n");

        string strNew;

        Console.Write("Input the string : ");
        strNew = Console.ReadLine();
        //string[] newStr = strNew.Split(' ');
        var ucWord = WordFilt(strNew);
        Console.Write("\nThe UPPER CASE words are :\n ");
        foreach (string strRet in ucWord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strRet);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

  static IEnumerable<string> WordFilt(string mystr)
    {
        var upWord =  mystr.Split(' ')
        .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && char.IsUpper(x[0]));
     return upWord;

    }
```